Nonograms that require more than single-line logic
Sparked by solving nonograms from a puzzle book, I decided to create a solver for nonograms. For now it is relatively simple: It just loops through all rows and columns individually, checks if there are any squares forced empty or filled, and adds that to the grid. Repeat until solved.
So far, this has been able to solve all nonograms from said puzzle book. However, part of this has left a weird feeling. When manually solving these puzzles, I tend to look at implications of filling certain squares by looking at the effects on nearby rows or columns. Perhaps I need this because rigorously checking for all forced squares in a line is a lot of work, but seemingly the tool I wrote does not need those tactics to solve at least the nonograms I have as sample.
So my question is as follows: do such nonograms exist, where you can't iteratively solve them line by line, without looking at anything but that specific line (slice of the grid) and the hints? For a nonogram to exist, they need to have a single valid solution.

The Wikipedia article claims that there are nonograms that "require several types of "what if?" reasoning"

Similarly with the Battleships game: the simpler ones can be solved by deciding the cell contents only from the current state of other lines. In the harder ones with multiple options you must make decisions like "this ship size can't be in both these two lines, so this other line must have one".

Hmm, I figured as much. It would be nice to have an example puzzle in an answer. I'll offer a 50 rep bounty (don't have much to spare ).

The smallest such puzzle is 4x2:
  which solves to 
No cell can be identified from any single line of clues, but the solution is unique. There are no 3x3 or smaller puzzles like this, as confirmed by code, and this is the only 4x2 up to reflection.

Yes, here's one:

You can, of course, mark the middle row and column as unused. But after that, there's no way to get any more information from a single row or column in isolation.

If we encounter this kind of situation "in the wild" (as part of a larger grid, for example, so this 5x5 pictured here is not contiguous), what heuristics can we employ to solve it?

@justhalf I'm not sure there's any beyond just testing assumptions: choose one of the possibilities, see if it leads to a contradiction, and if so go back to the initial assumption and repeat with a different possibility.

Here's one where you can't identify a single square with single-line logic:

Its solution is:

 


I have changed your text-based description to a visual one.  If you don’t approve, please feel free to rollback my edit.

A kind of contradiction logic can be used when long blocks appear close to the boundary but don't make progress by itself. This logic is a standard technique in Nonogram Galaxy series (which features mostly challenging 25x25 and 30x30 puzzles), and can be quite powerful as it reveals potentially many crosses and some fills near the boundary.
As a rather synthetic example, let's consider the following part of a puzzle. It shows only top two rows for a 8x8 puzzle, and only the topmost clue on each column.

Both [4] and [3, 1] are not enough to make progress on empty lines of width 8. However, we can assume each possible position of the 4 block and apply quick single-step deductions on columns to see if any of them causes a contradiction.
If the 4 starts at the 1st, 2nd, or 3rd column, there is no way to place the 3 on the second row:



On the other hand, if it is placed to the far right, it will interfere with the 1:

Therefore, there is only one way to put the 4 on the first row.

On a real puzzle of larger sizes, the flow of reasoning often goes like this:

If this block is placed on the far left, contradiction; therefore we can put an X on the leftmost cell.
If is placed on the next possible leftmost position, contradiction; put an X on the leftmost cell again.
Repeat until there is no immediate contradiction. Repeat from the far right.
If there is only one longish block, try positions in the middle as well, and mark X on some cells if every possible placement over it causes a contradiction.
Then try making progress on the line.


Nonogram Galaxy puzzles contain variations of xnor's grid as well, most of them being part of the smiling faces. Unlike the logic above, this appears at the endgame, and can be treated as a pattern as a whole.
A few contain even harder unpredictable contradictions. In these cases, the game offers a hint in the form of "if you assume this cell to be filled (or X), it will eventually lead to a contradiction". I haven't played the game for a long while, so I don't have an example to show, unfortunately.
